# Translate signals amplitude into frequency

Tags: communication, frequency, frequency-modulation

I have a sinusoidal signal at 50 Hz, that varies in amplitude, with no offset. The amplitude goes from 0 to 5 V (peak to peak), and the amplitude contains all the information I need. This signal will change abruptly (in amplitude) but not very frequently, by that I mean for example that it could be at 2Vpp for an hour and then suddenly change to 3Vpp.

What I want to do is transmit that information using FM. For that to work I will need to transform the signal into something which gives me the same information but now related to it's frequency. For example map the 0 to 5 V range into some frequency range so then I can modulate using a VCO. I would also need to demodulate this at the receptor, and will probably need to remap from frequency to voltage ater the signal is received. This I don't know how to do, so I'm asking for help here.

I don't know if I explained myself correctly, so I'll edit my question if needed. I know that FM may not be the best way to go here, but I have all the components I would need and I don't have the money to buy for some other option.

Comment: May we know why you would like to do this? You should be using a peak detector. If you're clever, you can even make it reset on zero crossings.

Comment: I'm using a hall effect current sensor which gives me the current as the signal I described. Yes, I can use a peak detector, and now how to implement it. The issue is that then I will have a DC signal which I don't know how to transmit using FM. That's why I'm asking about translating the amplitude information (or the DC signal from the peak detection) into frequency.

Comment: I think it is often buffered and used to bias a varicap diode in an oscillator circuit. I also think this means you require a superheterodyne receiver on the other end. My knowledge of FM isn't as handy as it could be

Answer (score 1):

Both Analog Devices and TI make a variety of voltage to frequency converters - just google "V to F converter" to get several links.

I've used the Burr-Brown (now TI) VFC32 - it does both voltage to frequency and frequency to voltage conversion.

If you are only concerned with the amplitude of the 50 Hz signal, and not its instantaneous value, I would first rectify the signal, to get the peak voltage, then apply that voltage to the VFC.

Comment: Actually transmitting the 50 Hz tone and peak-detecting at the receive end would enable eliminating errors in case the reference frequency of the FM transmitter or receiver drifts. Whether this is overkill depends on OP's accuracy needs.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually thinking about rectifying. Will read that chip datasheet. Do you know about one I could use to convert from F to V at the receiver?

Comment: @volotec: As I said, the VFC 32 will convert both ways - other V to F chips may do so as well, but I don't think I've used anything else myself.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I was thinking of doing that but then I thought that I would loose the information through the amplification stages. I actually don't know a lot about communications, but at least that's what it crossed my mind.